# Typeof error when connecting to MySQL databases in heroku app

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku

I have been trying to get my heroku app working properly for hours and I don't know what to do anymore. I am receiving the error: TypeError: pool.promise is not a function. The odd thing is that everything works fine on my laptop in the development environment.

My database.js file contains the following code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
const config = require('config');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: 'us-cdbr-iron-east-05.cleardb.net',
  user: 'b5ab7f7c8bed47',
  database: 'heroku_d28016f0657fae1',
  password: process.env.db_pass,
});

module.exports = pool.promise();   <---- This line recieves the Typeof error.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Make sure your paths are correct in your `require` statements. They may be different in the dev environment.

Comment: Did my comment above help?

Comment: Thanks you for commenting Rob. I checked the paths and they were right ( I think). The next error I kept getting was about promises not having a catch method and throwing an error. The error said it was coming from within the mysql2 module. I ended up uninstalling mysql2 and installed mysql. I used callbacks and everything worked fine.